# How to create post request in DRF

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I m working on this `POST` request in drf and I lost it somewhere please help.

my `models.py`

```
class TargetDefination(models.Model):
    targetName=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    displayName=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.targetName

class Target(models.Model):
    targetDefn=models.ForeignKey(TargetDefination,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    roleId=models.ForeignKey(Role,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    empId=models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    startDate= models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    endDate= models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    value=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.empId) + ' ' +str(self.targetDefn)
```

`serializer.py`

```
class TargetSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    targetDefn=TargetDefinationSerializers()
    roleId=RoleSerializers()
    empId=OnlyEmployeeSerializers()

    class Meta:
        model = Target
        fields = (
            'id',
            'targetDefn',
            'roleId',
            'empId',
            'startDate',
            'endDate',
            'value'
        )
```

and this is what I have tried:
`views.py`

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def setTarget(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method=='GET':
        setTrgt=Target.objects.all()
        serial=TargetSerializers(setTrgt,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serial.data,safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        serial=TargetSerializers(data=data)
        if serial.is_valid():
            print("working")
            target = serial.save()
            serializer = TargetSerializers(target)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK,safe=False)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I need to create POST request and the format will be:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "targetDefn": {
      "id": 1,
      "targetName": "MIN SALES",
      "displayName": "MIN SALES"
    },
    "roleId": {
      "id": 1,
      "roleName": "CEO",
      "description": "Chief executive officer",
      "roleReportsTo": null,
      "roleReportsToName": null
    },
    "empId": {
      "id": 5,
      "empName": "Emp05",
      "startDate": "2021-05-04",
      "termDate": null
    },
    "startDate": "2021-05-05",
    "endDate": null,
    "value": 123
  }
```

this is an example with just values in it.

errors I m getting:

```
The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `employee.serializers.TargetSerializers`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

Comment: What did you lose exactly?

Comment: What's not working and what errors do you get?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have added the errors.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement a `create()` method in your serializer. The implementation of this method should break the request data and then write it into its respective models.

Here is how you can implement the method -

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    #split the objects into multiple objects.

    targetDef = validated_data.pop(targetDefn)

    
    #save the objects into its respective models.
    targetDefId = TargetDefination.objects.create(**targetDef)
    
    #get the objects of roleId and empID
    role = list(validated_data['roleId'].items())
    role_id = Role.objects.get(roleName =role[0][1])
    emp_id = Employee.objects.get(pk=validated_data['empId']['id'])

    target_obj = Target.object.create(targetDef=targetDefId, roleId=role_id, empID=emp_id, startDate=validated_data['startDate'], endDate=validated_data['endDate'], value=validated_data['value'])

    return target_obj
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it throws me an error `KeyError: 'id'` at `role_id=Role.objects.get(pk=validated_data['roleId']['id'])` and when I print `validated_data['roleId']` it shows me `OrderedDict([('roleName', 'CEO'), ('description', 'Chief executive officer'), ('roleReportsTo', None)])`

Comment: and when I print `validated_data` it shows me this `OrderedDict([('targetName', 'MIN SALES'), ('displayName', 'MIN SALES')])
{'startDate': datetime.date(2021, 5, 5), 'endDate': None, 'value': 123}
`

Comment: @SandeepSharma I have updated the `create()` method try it. This might work.

Comment: thank you for a quick reply. error `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'CEO'`.

Comment: `print(list(validated_data['roleId'].items()))` shows me this `[('roleName', 'CEO'), ('description', 'Chief executive officer'), ('roleReportsTo', None)]`

Comment: @SandeepSharma I have again updated the answer try it with that

Comment: Yess!! it's working fine. but `role_id` giving me `CEO` not the id of role i.e `1`. can you explain to me why ? and how I fix that too?

Comment: well actually it is returning you the string representation of that instance. You can simply `role_id.id` to get the pk value of that instance.

Comment: Hey,@JeetPatel can you look into the problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079775/data-is-not-expected-in-nested-serializer