# data is not expected in nested serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I m making a post request. but the data is not giving me as expected.

`views.py`

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def ruleAssignment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer=RuleAssignmentParamsSerializers(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK,safe=False)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and `serializers.py` I have create function to split the objects and save the data in different models.

```
class RuleAssignmentParamsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ruleAssignmentDetails = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    targetDefination = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = RuleAssignmentParams
        fields = (
            'id',
            'ruleAssignmentDetails',
            'detailSrl',
            'parameterName',
            'valueType',
            'overwriteValue',
            'targetDefination',
        )

    def create(self,validated_data):
        print(f'validated_data',validated_data)
        ruleAssDetails = validated_data.pop('ruleAssignmentDetails')
        print(f'ruleAssDetails',ruleAssDetails)

    def get_ruleAssignmentDetails(self,obj):
        rule = RuleAssignmentDetails.objects.get(id=obj.ruleAssignmentDetails_id)
        serial = RuleAssignmentDetailsSerializers(rule)
        return serial.data
    
    def get_targetDefination(self,obj):
        rule = TargetDefination.objects.get(id=obj.targetDefination_id)
        serial = TargetDefinationSerializers(rule)
        return serial.data
```

and the object I m sending:

```
{
  "ruleAssignmentDetails": {
    "id": 1,
    "ruleAssignment": {
      "id": 1,
      "empId": 1,
      "roleId": 1,
      "empName": "Emp01",
      "roleName": "CEO"
    },
    "detailSrl": 12,
    "rule": 4,
    "validityType": "F",
    "startDate": "2021-06-14",
    "endDate": null,
    "frequency": {
      "id": 1,
      "frequencyName": "Test",
      "frequencyTpe": "Weekly"
    }
  },
  "detailSrl": 12,
  "parameterName": "Param1",
  "valueType": "D",
  "overwriteValue": null,
  "targetDefination": {
    "id": 1,
    "targetName": "MIN SALES",
    "displayName": "MIN SALES"
  }
}
```

and when I print(validated_data) in serializer it's giving me:

```
{'detailSrl': 12, 'parameterName': 'Param1', 'valueType': 'D', 'overwriteValue': None}
```

not the whole object. how do I get all the data in serializer to split the data into different models.
Just need to pass the objects to serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class RuleAssignmentParamsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ruleAssignmentDetails = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    targetDefination = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = RuleAssignmentParams
        fields = (
            'id',
            'ruleAssignmentDetails',
            'detailSrl',
            'parameterName',
            'valueType',
            'overwriteValue',
            'targetDefination',
        )
        depth = 1 <--- add this line in your code
```